# Laravel accessor not called when column name like column_a_name or coumn_10

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, accessor

I am using Laravel accessors and they are all working except two of them:

```
public function getLambdaDCheckboxAttribute($value)
{
    ...
}
```

where the name of the DB column is lambda_d_checkbox and

```
public function getUber40CheckboxAttribute($value)
{
   ...
}
```

where the DB column name is uber_40_checkbox.

I guess that the problem in the first example is the sing "d" letter between the two underscores and the number "40" in the second exaplme. How can I accomplish calling those accessors?

I have the following structure:

```
class UploadIconsRES extends Eloquent{
   private $verbesserte_text = "";
   private $verbesserte_image = "";
   private $lambda_d_text = "";
   private $lambda_d_image = "";

   public function getVerbesserteCheckboxAttribute($value)
   {
      if($value == "yes")
      {
          $this->verbesserte_image= 'http://h02b.ebau.at/austrotherm/1280/'.DB::table('upload_icons_url')->where('id', 1)->pluck('icon_url');
          $this->verbesserte_text = DB::table('upload_icons_text')->where('id', 1)->pluck('icon_name');
      }

      return $value;
   }

   public function getLambdaDCheckboxAttribute()
   {        
      if($this->lambda_d_checkbox == "yes")
      {
          $this->lambda_d_image ='http://h02b.ebau.at/austrotherm/1280/'.DB::table('upload_icons_url')->where('id', 34)->pluck('icon_url');
          $this->lambda_d_text = DB::table('upload_icons_text')->where('id', 34)->pluck('icon_name');
      }

      return $value;
  }

  public function toArray()
  {
     $array = parent::toArray();
     $array['icons'] =  array();

     if($this->verbesserte_image != "")
     {
        $icon =  array();
        $icon['url'] = $this->verbesserte_image;
        $icon['text'] = $this->verbesserte_text;

        array_push($array['icons'],  $icon);
     }  

     if($this->lambda_d_image != "")
     {
        $icon =  array();
        $icon['url'] = $this->lambda_d_image;
        $icon['text'] = $this->lambda_d_text;

        array_push($array['icons'],  $icon);
     }

     return $array;
  }
```

then...

```
class ProductMetaRES  extends Eloquent {

   protected $table = 'products_meta_res';
   protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';

   public function UploadIconsRES()
   {
       return $this->hasMany("UploadIconsRES", "productID", "id");
   }
}
```

then...

```
 class ProductLangRes extends Eloquent
 {
     protected $table = 'products_lang_res';

     public function ProductMetaRES()
     {
       return $this->hasOne("ProductMetaRES", "product_lang_FS");
     }
 }
```

And finally when I call use those classes in my controller like this:

```
$content = ProductLangRES::with( 'ProductMetaRES.UploadIconsRES')->get(array('id', 'de_AT as name', 'de_AT_description as description'));
```

I do not get the desired icon_url and icon_text. In addition I have more accessors in those classes that are working fine, but I didn't include them in the example here for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
public function getLambdaDCheckboxAttribute()
{
    return $this->lambda_d_checkbox;
}

public function getUber40CheckboxAttribute()
{
    return $this->uber_40_checkbox;
}
```

Comment: It's the same. The methods are never called.

Comment: How do you call them?

Comment: I do not call them. I expect to be called automatically by Laravel. Isn't it the way it works?

Comment: They only get called automatically of you are trying to access them. So what's happening exactly when you are trying to access it?

Comment: Well see, this is not how accessors work. The accessor is called when you are accessing it AFTER the database call like this: `$content->lamba_d_checkbox`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98126/discussion-between-ivan-nikolov-and-tim).